# Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this HW problem, we are asked to build a Class RandomBag -- a generic bag container which allows 'RandomPick' of an element.
I keep getting this error I have little idea to fix, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  public RandomBag() {
      ArrayList<E> Bag=new ArrayList<E>();
      Random Rand =new Random();
  }
  public RandomBag(int seed) { 
      ArrayList<E> Bag=new ArrayList<E>();
      Random Rand =new Random(seed);
```

Comment: what error and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never initializing the variables `rand` or `bag`, so they are always `null`. In your constructors you need to use `rand` and `bag`, not `Rand` or `Bag`. For example:

```
public RandomBag() {
    bag = new ArrayList<E>();
    rand = new Random();
}
```

Comment: you haven't even read the code, right?

Comment: whats wrong with it @Paul? this seems correct

Comment: @Baby as far as i can see, there are two constructors, and both initialize bag aswell as rand

Comment: @Paul no. Look closely. case-sensitive

Comment: @Paul also he declares them as new variables by defining the type, so even if they had the same name it would't define the ones he declares above.

Comment: oh, right didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

A few things, in your constructors change

```
ArrayList<E> Bag=new ArrayList<E>();
Random Rand =new Random();
```

to

```
bag=new ArrayList<E>();
rand = new Random(seed);
```

few things to remember:
variables are case sensitive.
if you add a type, you are defining, not setting, ie:

```
ArrayList<E> bag=new ArrayList<E>();
```

is defining a new variable `bag` while

```
bag=new ArrayList<E>();
```

sets the existing variable `bag` to `new ArrayList<E>();`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialise new variable in constructor. Assign it to variables that you have declared instead.

```
  public RandomBag(int seed) { 
  bag=new ArrayList<E>();
  rand =new Random(seed);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructors:

```
 public RandomBag() {
      bag = new ArrayList<E>();
      rand = new Random();
  }
  public RandomBag(int seed) { 
      bag = new ArrayList<E>();
      rand = new Random(seed);
  }
```

The output is:

10
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
Random pick: 15
Random pick: 16
Random pick: 13
10
10
11
12
14
17**

Answer (score -1):

In your constructors...
Replace

```
ArrayList<E> Bag=new ArrayList<E>();
  Random Rand =new Random(seed);
```

with

```
Bag=new ArrayList<E>();
   Rand =new Random(seed);
```

Comment: cannot find symbol Bag. cannot find symbol Rand

Comment: bag, not Bag, sorry, and rand, not Rand.

Comment: The idea is that you declare this instance variables in your class, but you do not initialize them in your constructors, but you declare other 2 local (to the constructors) variables and initialize them there, which has nothing to do with your instance variables (bag and random).

Comment: you can edit your post, not posting as a comment.